# Outlook 365 receives a message that has an attachment that is named "not supported calendar message.ics"

Tags: c#, .net, calendar, outlook, office365

I have a .NET application which sends meeting requests in the form of .ics files. Here are the few things that i am doing in order to make it work.

- Create a System.Net.Mail.MailMessage and set the usual fields
  (from/to/subject/etc) And the meeting info as an attachment (ICS
  File)
- Add alternate view and attach the generated .ics file

  AlternateView alternate = new AlternateView(vcsAttachment, "text/calendar; method=REQUEST;");
  msg.AlternateViews.Add(alternate);
- CreateAlternateViewFromString

  AlternateView alternate1 = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body), null, "text/html");
  msg.AlternateViews.Add(alternate1);

Scheduling meeting shows Accept, Declined buttons which is expected.
   http://screencast.com/t/lU08FiXowhc

**Issue here is:**
When updating the same meeting request or cancel the meeting request, recipient is receiving an email with attachment as **not supported calender message.ics**
http://screencast.com/t/kD89nbTa

Below is the .ics generated for scheduling a meeting.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:participant@company.com
ORGANIZER;CN="Organizer":MAILTO:organizer@test.ccc
DTSTART:20141231T010000Z
DTEND:20141231T010000Z
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SEQUENCE:0
UID:Company-interview-123
DTSTAMP:20141223T232322Z
SUMMARY:Interview Scheduled for Job
DESCRIPTION:test
LOCATION:Test Location
PRIORITY:5
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
CLASS:PUBLIC
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

.ics file generated for rescheduling meeting request.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:participant@company.com
ORGANIZER;CN="Organizer":MAILTO:organizer@test.ccc
DTSTART:20141231T010000Z
DTEND:20141231T010000Z
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SEQUENCE:1
UID:Company-interview-123
DTSTAMP:20141223T232538Z
SUMMARY:Updated Interview Scheduled for Job
DESCRIPTION:test
LOCATION:Test Location
PRIORITY:5
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
CLASS:PUBLIC
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Am i missing something here? For other email clients, its working fine and I am able to view the meeting request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've also run into issue with "not supported calender message.ics" when iCalendar **ORGANIZER**'s address was not equal to email (meeting request) **FROM** address. Make sure that they are equal in your second case with rescheduling.

**UPDATE:** Test code that sends iCalendar as the **only** AlternativeView shows that both iCalendar messages you've provided are itself fine. Please, see the screenshot from OWA:

[image]

Comment: Yes your suggestion worked. Organizer's and from address must be same. Its working fine on outlook 365. All other email clients are working fine even if they we have different from address. Looks like other email clients are just looking at Organizers's and UID.

Comment: @nimi, nice to hear it! I spent hours when I stuck into similar trouble and googled no viable suggestions, so happy to share the solution.

Answer (score 2):

In our .NET Application we have this issue with .ics calendar events.

The solution from @Eugene D. Gubenkov for making **FROM** address to be same as **ORGANIZER** address works, but won't work when Amazon Simple Email Service (SES) is used for sending emails because **FROM** addresses previously must be approved in Amazon SES.

We fix this issue with setting value to **SentBy** property (https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net/blob/master/v2/ical.NET/DataTypes/Organizer.cs).

```
CalendarEvent calendarEvent = new CalendarEvent();
string organizer = "email-organizer@example.com";
string defaultFromEmailAddress = "email-from@example.com";
calendarEvent.Organizer = new Organizer()
{
    Value = new Uri("mailto:" + organizer),
    SentBy = new Uri("mailto:" + defaultFromEmailAddress)
};
```

After this changes, the generated .ics looks like:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:-//github.com/rianjs/ical.net//NONSGML ical.net 4.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:email-organizer@example.com
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:attendee1@example.com
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:attendee2@example.com
DESCRIPTION:Description for this meeting
DTEND:20190927T163000Z
DTSTAMP:20190927T111043Z
DTSTART:20190927T153000Z
LOCATION:Slack
ORGANIZER;SENT-BY="mailto:email-from@example.com":mailto:
email-organizer@example.com
PRIORITY:0
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Description for this meeting
TRANSP:OPAQUE
UID:194e3146-ba93-4e32-9175-6aecbe87b682
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//
 EN\">\n<html>\n<head>\n    <meta charset="utf-8" />\n    <title></title>\
 n</head>\n<body>\n    <label>Meeting T
 itle: Meeting to test ics calendar</label>\n    <br />\n    <label>Date: 
 09.27.2019 - 09.27.2019</label>\n    <br />\n    <label>Time: 5:30 PM - 6
 :30 PM</label>\n    <br />\n    <label>Location: Slack</label>\n    <br /
 >\n    <p>Please respond to the event to process the invitation and updat
 e your calendar. Additional meeting details and the agenda may be found <
 a href="http://URLToMeetingDetailsPage">here</a>
 </p></body>\n</html>
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Main difference is this line where **SENT-BY** is added

`ORGANIZER;SENT-BY="mailto:email-from@example.com":mailto:email-organizer@example.com`

Screenshot from Calendar event in Outlook:
[Calendar event in Outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEp4j.png)

Answer (score 0):

The ICS file must not be sent as an attachment. It must be the one and only MIME part of the message with the correctly set content-type header.

Answer (score 0):

@nimi: Just to reiterate the fact that this wierd behaviour is found to be specific to Office 365 accounts.
Here's a link to a support ticket opened in the Office 365 community helpline site:
[MS Community issue link](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/288792.aspx)
There aren't any updates from MS Support Staff on it yet, so for now the only solution seems to be to set the **ORGANIZER:mailto:** address to be same as the **FROM:** email address.